# Apache Camel mail to identify auto generated messages

Tags: email, apache-camel, auto-generate

I'm looking for a way to identify auto generated messages like Outlook's "Out of office" replies.

I stumbled upon a header called "Auto-submitted" that's supposed to do the trick, but [Camel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Camel) doesn't seems to provide this header in the "Message" object. Reference: `http://www.iana.org/assignments/auto-submitted-keywords/auto-submitted-keywords.xml`

Is it possible to know if a message is auto generated or human generated?

Comment: Hmm camel-mail does propagate all the MailMessage headers to the Camel Message, at least in the source code :). I wonder if you can see other kind of headers?

Comment: I tried to look inside the headers but i can't find anything that can tell me if the message was auto generated or not.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/301958/8479

Answer (score 6):

I don't know Apache Camel, but I can tell you that there is no simple and safe way to detect automated email messages in general. Headers like *auto-submitted* are an indicator, but unfortunately lots of automated scripts do not add them. I once had to write an out-of-office implementation that should not send ooo replies to any automated messages (mailing lists, spam, newsletters, etc.). Here is what I finally came up with, maybe this helps in your case as well:

**Sender address regular expressions** that indicate automated senders:

- "^owner-"
- "^request-"
- "-request@"
- "bounce.*@"
- "-confirm@"
- "-errors@"
- "^no[-]?reply"
- "^donotreply"
- "^postmaster@"
- "^mailer[-_]daemon@"
- "^mailer@"
- "^listserv@"
- "^majordom[o]?@"
- "^mailman@"
- "^nobody@"
- "^bounce"
- "^www(-data)?@"
- "^mdaemon@"
- "^root@"
- "^news(letter)?@"
- "^webmaster@" (role address - may not be a good indicator in your case)
- "^administrator@" (role address - may not be a good indicator in your case)
- "^support@"  (role address - may not be a good indicator in your case)

**Headers** that indicate automated messages if they **exist**:

- list-help
- list-unsubscribe
- list-subscribe
- list-owner
- list-post
- list-archive
- list-id
- mailing-List
- x-facebook-notify
- x-mailing-list
- x-cron-env
- x-autoresponse
- x-eBay-mailtracker

**Headers** that indicate automated messages if they have **a special value**:

- 'x-spam-flag':'yes'
- 'x-spam-status':'yes'
- 'X-Spam-Flag2': 'yes'
- 'precedence':'(bulk|list|junk)'
- 'x-precedence':'(bulk|list|junk)'
- 'x-barracuda-spam-status':'yes'
- 'x-dspam-result':'(spam|bl[ao]cklisted)'
- 'X-Mailer':'^Mail$'
- 'auto-submitted':'auto-replied'

Comment: I'll check those out. Thanks a lot !

Comment: I just tried to look for any of those headers in an autoreply outlook generated and none of the exist ...

Comment: yes, unfortunately, the outlook ooo assistant does not add any of those. that's why out-of-office implementations usually also have a rule to send only one reply per sender and day, to avoid flooding each other. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027395/detecting-outlook-autoreply-out-of-office-emails

Comment: I just checked a bunch of ms outlook generated replies. *some* of them have a header : X-Auto-Response-Suppress: All .

Comment: I didn't see that header. Thanks anyway. I suppose that the link you gave here is enough to understand that there's no solution using headers. Too bad :(