# How do I prevent auto-replys (out-of-office/ DNR/etc) to my automated emails? (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, email, html-email, email-headers

I have a bulk emailer that sends marketing updates to a list of users. We want legitimate responses from our users to come back to our customer service email address, but for reasons irrelevant to the problem, I can't filter them out on the receiving end.

I'm wondering if there's a header, or something I can add that prevents auto-responses from being returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more digging for an answer that seems like a pretty common problem than I was prepared for, I stumbled on this question about [how to suppress auto-replys in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62365337/how-to-send-an-email-in-ews-c-with-suppress-auto-responses) that took me down a Microsoft wormhole into MSDN docs, mentioning the `X-Auto-Response-Suppress` header - [more on this headers options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxcmail/ced68690-498a-4567-9d14-5c01f974d8b1)

[It's also mentioned, but not explained in the symphony Docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html#message-headers)

What I found was yes, there is a header that can be attached, and from what I can tell, it has varying levels of success with being honored by different email servers. Microsoft/Exchange seems to have the most documentation around it, so I suspect they support it pretty widely, but I don't have experience with actually using this yet - will update after implementation.

I'm formatting this for Laravel, but the header should be widely applicable to any language/framework.

Here's how to add to an email builder in laravel:

```
/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    $this->view('emails.orders.shipped');
 
    $this->withSwiftMessage(function ($message) {
        $message->getHeaders()->addTextHeader(
            'X-Auto-Response-Suppress', 'OOF, DR, RN, NRN, AutoReply'
        );
    });
 
    return $this;
}
```

Here are the keys and their meaning:

| Key | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| DR | Suppress delivery reports from transport. |
| NDR | Suppress non-delivery reports from transport. |
| RN | Suppress read notifications from receiving client. |
| NRN | Suppress non-read notifications from receiving client. |
| OOF | Suppress Out of Office (OOF) notifications. |
| AutoReply | Suppress auto-reply messages other than OOF notifications. |
| None | Don't suppress anything |
| All | Suppress everything |