# How to differentiate between the automatic reply and the normal mail received

Tags: java, spring-boot, email, imap, multipart

I am working on receiving mails in my springboot application. In order to fetch and store the receive mails. I am using imap mail listener. There are two types of mails which I am storing. One is multipart payload type and the other is string payload type.

After receiving mail I am trying to send an auto-generated mails using java mail.
The issue which I am facing is worst case scenario of generating auto-reply from my application i.e infinite loop.

Can someone help ow can I differentiate between a normal mail received and auto-reply received in my mail box and generate auto-replies from my system only for those mails which are not auto-reply type.

It would be nice if explained via code for headers check. I came across through few headers like x-Autosubmitted. But they are returning null if I am trying to print the values in console.

Comment: Can this help @gursimran sondhi : https://www.jitbit.com/maxblog/18-detecting-outlook-autoreplyout-of-office-emails-and-x-auto-response-suppress-header/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027395/detecting-outlook-autoreply-out-of-office-emails

Comment: [3834 section 2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3834#section-2) answers this well. You may also want to read [5230 section 4.6](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5230#section-4.6), even if the rest of that document is irrelevant to you. The [60-70 lines that sometimes set wantToReply to false](https://github.com/aox/aox/blob/9730b5f98b43316be1180654f3d3bec24a549ac2/sieve/sieve.cpp#L829) may provide some inspiration. Finally, delaying your own response by half a minute is a fine mitigation in case someone else's autoresponder sucks and there's a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [auto-submmitted](http://www.iana.org/assignments/auto-submitted-keywords/auto-submitted-keywords.xhtml) markers are described below that you may find helpful:

- *auto-generated* - Indicates that a message was generated by an automatic process, and is not a direct response to another message.
- *auto-replied*   - Indicates that a message was automatically generated as a direct response to another message.
- *auto-notified*  - Indicates that a message was generated by a Sieve notification system.
- *no*  - Indicates that a message was NOT automatically generated, but was created by a human. It is the equivalent to the absence of an Auto-Submitted header altogether.

The [RFC 2822](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt) states the following:

```
Though optional, every message SHOULD have a "Message-ID:" field.
Furthermore, reply messages SHOULD have "In-Reply-To:"
```

So, you may check for the "In-Reply-To:" value in the header.

Also you may add your own value to the outgoing email, so you may distinguish between an automatically generated reply from your system and manually created.