# Catching a Email Loop from a out of office agent

Tags: smtp, email-bounces

Our Current email2fax gateway does not handle bounced emails very well. When a email is sent to the gateway the content is faxed out and a notification is sent to the original sender of the message.

Problems happen when the original user turns on a out of office agent and messages will bounces between the 2 email gateways.

I have tried to set in the outbound notification the following headers

From
Reply-To

But as this is a proprietary gateway it does not allow me to set a custom Return-PATH
some silly mail servers send replies back to that.

Are there any extra email headers that maybe I could set to say "Do not send a Notification back"

If not is there a email gateway that would be able to act like a proxy and sit in front of the gateway that would then allow me to programmable check the messages as they came in and drop out of office messages.

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought an anti-spam program like SpamAssassin could be fine-tuned to catch out-of-office replies.

If your mail gateway can't even have an anti-spam system plugged into it then it really is a bad system to have around!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `Precedence: bulk`-header (or `junk`) in your notifications. Usually OOO-notifiers like Unix `vacation` do not send notifications for incoming mails with that header.

As this header is slightly discouraged, you could try setting an empty `Return-Path`, as suggested in [Precedence: header in email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154718/precedence-header-in-email).