# What heuristics should I use to prevent an autoresponder war?

Tags: email

I am currently extending an e-mail system with an autoresponse feature. In a dark past, I've seen some awesome mail loops, and I'm now trying to avoid such a thing from happening to me.

I've looked at how other tools ('mailbot', 'vacation') are doing this, grepped my own mail archive for suspicious mail headers, but I wonder if there is something else I can add.

My process at this point:

1. Refuse if sender address is invalid (this should get rid of messages with <> sender)
2. Refuse if sender address matches one of the following:
   `'^root@',
       '^hostmaster@',
       '^postmaster@',
       '^nobody@',
       '^www@',
       '-request@'`
3. Refuse if one of these headers (after whitespace normalization and lowercasing) is present:
   `'^precedence: junk$',
       '^precedence: bulk$',
       '^precedence: list$',
       '^list-id:',
       '^content-type: multipart/report$',
       '^x-autogenerated: reply$',
       '^auto-submit: yes$',
       '^subject: auto-response$'`
4. Refuse if sender address was already seen by the autoresponder in the recent past.
5. Refuse if the sender address is my own address :)
6. Accept and send autoresponse, prepending `Auto-response:` to the subject, setting headers `Precedence: bulk` and `Auto-Submit: yes` to hopefully prevent some remote mailer from propagating the autoresponse any further.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Part of the SMTP standard allows for asking a mail server whether or not a user is real.  Some are setup to always respond yes. Others will tell you the truth.  These autoresponses most likely come from invented e-mail addresses.  Not sure what the technical procedure to access this data is or how expensive time wise the look up would be, but worth investigating.

Answer (score 4):

In my research so far I've come up with these rules.

#### Treat inbound message as autogenerated, ignore it and blacklist the sender if...

- `Return-Path` header is `<>` or missing/invalid
- `Auto-Submitted` header is present with any value other than "no"
- `X-Auto-Response-Suppress` header is present
- `In-Reply-To` header is missing

  - **Note**: If I'm reading [RFC3834](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3834) correctly, your own programs SHOULD set this, but so far it seems some autoresponders omit this (freshdesk.com)

#### When sending outbound messages, be sure to...

- Set the `Auto-Submitted: auto-generated` header (or `auto-replied` as appropriate)
- Set your SMTP `MAIL FROM:` command with the null address `<>`

  - Note some delivery services including Amazon SES will set their own value here, so this may not be feasible
- Check the recipient against the blacklist built up by the inbound side and abort sending to known autoresponders
- Consider sending not more than 1 message per unit time (long like 24 hours) to a given recipient

#### Notes on other answers and points

- I think ignoring `Precedence: list` messages will cause false positives, at least for my app's configuration
- I believe the OP's "auto-submit" rule is a typo and the official header is `Auto-Submitted`

#### References

- [RFC3834](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3834)
- [This SO question about Precedence header](https://stackoverflow.com/q/154718/266795) has several good answers
- [Wikipedia Email Loop Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_loop)
- [desk.com article](https://support.desk.com/customer/portal/articles/1167831-preventing-an-email-war-email-loop)

---

Comments welcome and I'll update this answer as this is a good question and I'd like to see an authoritative answer created.

Comment: `In-Rely-To`? Apart from the typo, I'd say that this field will be missing on all mails that _start_ a thread, too, not only on auto-responder mails.

Answer (score 3):

Update 2014-05-22

To find if an inbound message is an "out-of-office" or other automatic reply, we use that procedure:

First, Find if header "In-Reply-To" is present.  If not, that is an auto-reply.

Else, check if 1 of these header is present:

- X-Auto-Response-Suppress (any value)
- Precedence (value contains bulk, or junk or list)
- X-Webmin-Autoreply (value 1)
- X-Autogenerated (value Reply)
- X-AutoReply (value YES)

Answer (score 1):

Include a phrase like "This is an automatically-generated response" in the body somewhere.  If your message body is HTML (not plain text) you can use a style to make it not visible.

Check for this phrase before responding.  If it exists, odds are good it's an automated response.

Comment: I believe some spam detection routines look for invisible text. Just a thought.

Comment: I like this; it should catch cases where other mailers respond to me quoting my own text.

Comment: I expect real users to reply to my email quoting original test and vacation autoresponder message to be sent without my original email.

Comment: @Tomas Tintera: Quoted text is usually easy to spot.  If the user is so clever that they quoted without their mailer inserting any hint that the quoted, then they win the prize for getting an autoresponse to their quote.   There's no way to be 100% perfect in detecting the amazing things that people are capable of doing.

Comment: Using the `Auto-Submitted: auto-replied` header is a much more standard compliant method (and SHOULD suppress auto-responses from other standard compliant autoresponders)